# How do I post from Instagram to a Squarespace blog?

Tags: gmail, blogs, instagram, foursquare

After a good amount of research today I figured it would be helpful if I wrote up what I have found to be a solid way to get Instagram posts automatically, not into a block, but directly into your blog on your foursquare blog (or other blogs that accept posts from email).

Comment: This solution will no longer work after December 6, 2016. Squarespace has announced it will be removing its Post by Email feature on that date.

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisites: A Gmail Account, and IFTTT account

Firstly in the settings for your blog turn on post by email. Then set up a trigger at IFTTT.com. The trigger is if a new photo is posted to your instagram send an email from your Gmail. The trigger is then set up to send the email to your GMail, subject can be whatever you'd like, I chose instagram: the body of the email is:

```
{{SourceUrl}} {{Caption}}
```

You then create a google script at script.google.com the script is: (must modify depending on your email address, subject you chose for email, and the email address you must send to for posting to your blog).

```
function sendCorrectEmail() {
  var instagramThreads = GmailApp.search('from:(justinhenricks@gmail.com) to:(justinhenricks@gmail.com) subject:(instagram:)', 0, 25);

  for(var i = 0; i < instagramThreads.length; i++) {
    var messages = instagramThreads[i].getMessages();

    for(var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();
      var urlEndIndex = body.indexOf(" ");
      var url = body.substring(0, urlEndIndex);
      var content = body.substring(urlEndIndex + 1, body.length - 1);

      var newBody = "<center><img src='" + url + "' /><br /><br /><i>instagram: </i>" + content + "  </center>";


      GmailApp.sendEmail("pbm+justin-henricks+j4p937@squarespace.com", "", newBody);
    }   
  }

  //delete all threads
  if(instagramThreads.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(instagramThreads);
  } 
};
```

Of course format the HTML to whatever you seem fit. The script simply checks your email for emails sent by you, to you, with a subject of instagram: it then takes the body of the email if it found one and separates the img URL from the content, it then formats those two variables into a little bit of HTML and sends a new email out to the address accepted by your blog.

Lastly, you're going to want to click Resources on the google script and add a trigger for the method to be executed every x amount of time. That way it will continuously check if there has been new instagram posts, and it will post them automatically.

I spent a few hours on this and although at first there seemed like there were less complicated ways to achieve this, there turned out not to be. If you are content with simply having a separate instagram block on your site SquareSpace can do this for you. I wanted my blog to contain my blog posts, and instagram posts all in one. This script can also very easily be modified to handle Twitter, Facebook etc all you would need to do is set up different IFTTT triggers and write new methods. Good luck!